# Как записать объект в базу json-server?

Tags: post, typescript, angular

Не могу понять, почему не происходит запись объекта в базу данных json-server. Все развернуто локально, аналогичный код работает в другом компоненте.

Вот модель:

```
export class Paei {

    constructor(
        public person_id: number,
        public date: string,
        public skill_p: number,
        public skill_a: number,
        public skill_e: number,
        public skill_i: number
        ) {}
}
```

Вот код метода, который не срабатывает:

```
  pushPaei() {
    this.skilldata = this.valuesService.getSkillResult();

    console.log(this.skilldata);

    this.paei = new Paei(
      this.personId,
      moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
      this.skilldata[0],
      this.skilldata[1],
      this.skilldata[2],
      this.skilldata[3]
    );

    console.log(this.paei);

    this.sub2 = this.paeiService.addPaei(this.paei)
    .subscribe(() => {});

    this.router.navigate(['/assessment/paei-result', this.personId]);

  }
```

И код сервиса:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Paei } from 'src/app/assessment/paei-test/models/paei.model';
import { BaseApi } from '../core/base-api';

@Injectable()

export class PaeiService extends BaseApi {
    paei: Paei;

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        super(http);
    }

    addPaei(paei: Paei): Observable<Paei> {

        console.log(this.paei);

        return this.post('paei', paei);
    }

    updatePaei(paei: Paei): Observable<Paei> {
        return this.put(`paei/${paei.person_id}`, paei);
      }

    deletePaeiById(id: number): Observable<Paei> {
        return this.delete(`paei/${id}`);
    }

    getPaeiById(id: number): Observable<Paei> {
        return this.get(`paei/${id}`);
    }

}
```

Там, где console.log получаю undefined, хотя в методе выше в сервис передается правильный объект Paei

Comment: у вас куча консоль логов - в каком именно `undefined`?

Comment: В последнем из них, который в сервисе. Предыдущие все возвращают правильно

Comment: а с чего вы взяли что вы там должны получить не `undefined`? свойство `paei` нигде не сеттится

Comment: this.sub2 = this.paeiService.addPaei(this.paei)
    .subscribe(() => {});. Здесь в сервис  передаю аргументом. Сеттится выше

Comment: я не вижу где тут сеттится свойство `paei`, `pushPaei` это метод какого класса?

Comment: this.paei = new Paei(
      this.personId,
      moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
      this.skilldata[0],
      this.skilldata[1],
      this.skilldata[2],
      this.skilldata[3]
    ); А это что?

Comment: вы не ответили на вопрос

Comment: Класс целиком не стал копировать, портянка. Но уверяю, объект paei обьявлен и  в консоли выводится правильно. Мне кажется, что где то связь между компонентом и сервисом нарушена. Здесь не показал app.module

Comment: ЕЩЕ РАЗ, `pushPaei` это метод какого класса?

Comment: Класса PaeiTestComponent

Comment: эм, то есть вы сеттите свойство `paei` в классе компонента, а пытаетесь получить к нему доступ в сервисе? :)

Comment: я передаю экземпляр класса в сервис, а не пытаюсь получить к нему доступ из сервиса

Comment: вы пытаетесь, `console.log(this.paei)` где `this` указывает на инстанс сервиса, `console.log(paei)` - и будет вам счастье

Comment: да, в точку)) но счастье не полное.... так как все равно в базу не пишет

Comment: это не проблема angular

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался самостоятельно. Решил изменением кода метода. Перенес навигацию в тело subscribtion

pushPaei() {
    this.skilldata = this.valuesService.getSkillResult();

```
console.log(this.skilldata);

this.paei = new Paei(
  this.personId,
  moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
  this.skilldata[0],
  this.skilldata[1],
  this.skilldata[2],
  this.skilldata[3]
);

console.log(this.paei);

this.sub2 = this.paeiService.addPaei(this.paei)
.subscribe(() => {
  this.router.navigate(['/assessment/paei-result', this.personId]);
});
```

}